# Computational intelligence-based methods for time series forecasting?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I know that ARIMA is one approach widely used in forecasting of univariate time series. What are some *computational intelligence* based methods that are reported to be successfully used in the same area? If possible, please recommend some articles/reports presenting such approaches.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most used CI-based technique for forecasting are the Neural Networks (NNs), you can find several reviews about NN application on forecasting. A good but not recent one is [this one](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207097000447) and [this one](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=910780) is instead on short-term load forecasting.

Other CI-based methods are not very common, maybe there are few fuzzy logic-based approaches (also neuro-fuzzy).

However, a little bit of Google Scholar can help you to find all the references you need.